# Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier

Tags: ios, terminal, xcode-ui-testing, watchos, uitest

Currently, I am struggling with the following issue and it's kind of big blocker for our project.
We need to run ui tests for apple watch test target in the iOS App with Watch App using terminal and we receive such error, which is quite frustrating

**Command I use:**

`xcodebuild test -workspace WatchTesterApp.xcworkspace -scheme 'Watch' -destination 'id=F35DCC98-0F7D-460E-A49F-A446FD5FB4BE'`

**xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
{ id:F35DCC98-0F7D-460E-A49F-A446FD5FB4BE }**

```
The requested device could not be found because no available devices matched the request.

Available destinations for the "Watch" scheme:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F35DCC98-0F7D-460E-A49F-A446FD5FB4BE, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 12 Pro }

Ineligible destinations for the "Watch" scheme:
    { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
    { platform:watchOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDevicePlaceholder-watchos:placeholder, name:Any watchOS Device }
```

Destination is iPhone's simulator id which is paired with apple watch

Has anyone faced such issue?

Answer (score 2):

So, after a long investigation and a long list of possible fixes that resolved nothing, I updated Xcode and tried to run the same command, which didn't work either and only after creating new clean project using new Xcode it finally worked.

I used:

```
xcodebuild test -workspace WatchTesterAppExample.xcworkspace -scheme 'WatchTesterAppExample WatchKit App' -destination 'platform=WatchOS Simulator,name=Apple Watch Series 7 - 45mm' & 
xcodebuild test -workspace WatchTesterAppExample.xcworkspace -scheme 'WatchTesterAppExample' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 13'
```

It worked for me on the simulators, didn't try it on real device yet

**Interesting fact**: I am still able to see this error in some case, especially when I don't specify platform in the 'destination'